# How to add navigation keys to tview?

Tags: go, tui

In my app, I want to change focus between my lists based on short keys. The demo gif shows it at the bottom, but I can't find any reference to it in the API. I can implement a `SetInputCapture` function on the `Application` instance, but it doesn't show the user the keys. Is there any way to do it?

[image]